# Tell clang-format to not add newline after control statement

Tags: clang, code-formatting, clang-format

When I have this minimal program

```
int main(void) {
        for (;;) ;
        if (0) return 1;
}
```

clang-format is adding a new line before the statements:

```
int main(void)
{
        for (;;)
                ;
        if (0)
                return 1;
}
```

How can I tell it to leave control statements without `{`, as they are. To make an example, when I have

```
int main(void)
{
        for (;;) ;
        if (0)
                return 1;
}
```

running clang-format on it should do nothing. I cannot find a configuration option for it. My .clang-format file is:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
#
# clang-format configuration file. Intended for clang-format >= 4.
#
# For more information, see:
#
#   Documentation/process/clang-format.rst
#   https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html
#   https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html
#
---
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
#AlignEscapedNewlines: Left # Unknown to clang-format-4.0
AlignOperands: true
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct: false
  AfterUnion: false
  #AfterExternBlock: false # Unknown to clang-format-5.0
  BeforeCatch: false
  BeforeElse: false
  IndentBraces: false
  #SplitEmptyFunction: true # Unknown to clang-format-4.0
  #SplitEmptyRecord: true # Unknown to clang-format-4.0
  #SplitEmptyNamespace: true # Unknown to clang-format-4.0
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
#BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false # Unknown to clang-format-4.0
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
#BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma # Unknown to clang-format-4.0
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: false
ColumnLimit: 80
CommentPragmas: '^ IWYU pragma:'
#CompactNamespaces: false # Unknown to clang-format-4.0
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 8
ContinuationIndentWidth: 8
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
#FixNamespaceComments: false # Unknown to clang-format-4.0

#IncludeBlocks: Preserve # Unknown to clang-format-5.0
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex: '.*'
    Priority: 1
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IndentCaseLabels: false
#IndentPPDirectives: None # Unknown to clang-format-5.0
IndentWidth: 8
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd: ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
#ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto # Unknown to clang-format-5.0
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 8
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true

# Taken from git's rules
#PenaltyBreakAssignment: 10 # Unknown to clang-format-4.0
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 30
PenaltyBreakComment: 10
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 100
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60

PointerAlignment: Right
ReflowComments: false
SortIncludes: false
#SortUsingDeclarations: false # Unknown to clang-format-4.0
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
#SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true # Unknown to clang-format-5.0
#SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true # Unknown to clang-format-5.0
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
#SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true # Unknown to clang-format-5.0
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: Cpp03
TabWidth: 8
UseTab: Always
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the documentation for `OnASingleLine`:
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

You will find:

```
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: [Never | Empty | Always]

AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: [Never | WithoutElse | OnlyFirstIf | AllIfsAndElse]
```

And many more for Switch statements, lambdas...